# SQL - Change Format of Date Type Varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, format, varchar

I am working on a table where the `dateofbirth` column is of type `varchar(50)`.

Date values in this column are in various formats.

I want to display them all in the following format: `DD/MM/yyyy`

I tried testing values like the following:

```
declare @testString1 as varchar(50) = '02/19/2015'
declare @testString2 as varchar(50) = '19/02/2015'
declare @testString3 as varchar(50) = '2015/02/19'

declare @converted1 as date = CONVERT(date,@testString1)
declare @converted2 as date = CONVERT(date,@testString2)
declare @converted3 as date = CONVERT(date,@testString3)
```

They all returned the value : `2015-02-19`

I tried then converting the date to varchar again:

```
SELECT convert(varchar,@converted1,105)
```

Which also returned `2015-02-19`

Why am I not able to convert from date to varchar in the format  `DD/MM/yyyy`?

Please note that I am fixing someone else's mess. I did not create this table and I know it is a bad idea to store datetimes in varchar.
I just need a temporary solution and the right `select query` before I change the format back to datetime.

Comment: Fix the data to store them as dates, the proper format.  And, you have to decide what a date like '03/07/2015' means . . . Is it March 7th or July 3rd?

Comment: @Terradon  I am working with a table after somebody else. i know its a bad idea :) I need something to manage before I change the table format.

Comment: add an extra field with a date type. then update these fields with the values  of your "bad column" ()convert these values in your sql statement). You haven't told which database / script you are using.

Comment: tagged as mysql server. I am unfaliair with it. So the sql you need, i leave it to other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
select RIGHT('0'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,day(GETDATE())),2) + '-' + RIGHT('0'+ 
CONVERT(VARCHAR,month(GETDATE())),2) + '-' + 
RIGHT('0000'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,year(GETDATE())),4)
```

OR :

```
Select CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 105) AS nvarchar(20))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need precise format syle when you're converting strings to dates and vice versa.

If you need to convert date to nvarchar using `DD/MM/yyyy` format - then you need **103** instead of **105** (which is `dd-mm-yyyy`) as format style.

For example: `select convert(nvarchar(20), getdate(), 103)` returns `16/10/2015`

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28CONVERT_TSQL%29;k%28SQL12.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1%29;k%28SQL12.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1%29;k%28MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT%29;k%28DevLang-TSQL%29&rd=true) for details concerning various format styles.

Also - storing dates in table as varchar instead of datetime doesn't seems like a good idea for me - so probably you should refactor your table and convert these values into datetime.

Comment: indeed, problem seems also the different kind of bad formats. So probably need a script first to detect which format and then use an according sql for it?